# Exclude test projects from Ndepend Analysis

Tags: ndepend

I have a visual studio solution which has a lot of projects including unit test projects. I am using NDepend API to analyze the solution. The intention is to get the relationship between methods. I am doing this by using MethodsCalled and MethodsCallingMe. Since there are test projects in the solution. I am ending up with lot many relationships as the unit testcases call the actual implementation, which is unnecessary for what I am trying to achieve.

Is there a way to exclude unit test projects when analyzing the solution?

[Ndepend - exclude assembly in some ways but not others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415535/ndepend-exclude-assembly-in-some-ways-but-not-others)
The link has some information not sure if this can be used with NDepend API.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting your assemblies through [this code](https://www.ndepend.com/api/webframe.html?NDepend.API_gettingstarted.html)?

```
// 2) obtains assemblies file path to analyze
var assembliesFilePath = (from vsSlnOrProjFilePath in vsSlnOrProjFilePaths
                           from assembliesFilePathTmp in visualStudioManager.GetAssembliesFromVisualStudioSolutionOrProject(vsSlnOrProjFilePath)
                           select assembliesFilePathTmp).Distinct().ToArray();
```

What about a LINQ filtering by assembly name, something like:

```
visualStudioManager.GetAssembliesFromVisualStudioSolutionOrProject(vsSlnOrProjFilePath)
.Where(a => !a.Name.ToLower().Contains("test"))
```